# CSS Child Selector Patterns

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I’ve build flexbox grid and was wondering what would be the best practice to set a structure or some kind of pattern which is repeating on some point. For now I am using the :nth-child selector. But I want to avoid hundreds of selectors only for a grid.

Here is a quick example I've made:

**CODE:**

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
}

.item {
  margin: 50px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
}

.projectTitle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  top: 100%;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  width: 26%;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  width: 27%;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  width: 26%;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  width: 29%;
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
  flex-basis: 27%;
}

.item:nth-child(6) {
  flex-basis: 26%;
}

.item:nth-child(7) {
  flex-basis: 36%;
}

.item:nth-child(8) {
  flex-basis: 36%;
}

.item:nth-child(9) {
  width: 26%;
}

.item:nth-child(10) {
  flex-basis: 29%;
}

.item:nth-child(11) {
  flex-basis: 26%;
}

.item:nth-child(12) {
  flex-basis: 75%;
}

.item:nth-child(13) {
  width: 26%;
}

.item:nth-child(14) {
  flex-basis: 29%;
}

.item:nth-child(15) {
  flex-basis: 26%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/875x1200">
      <div class="projectTitle">
        Hello<br><span>Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x655">
      <div class="projectTitle">
        Hello<br><span>Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/475x650">
      <div class="projectTitle">
        Hello<span>Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x450">
      <div class="projectTitle">
        Hello<span>Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/875x625">
      <div class="projectTitle">
        Hello<span>Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/655x480">
      <div class="projectTitle">
        Hello<span>Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/475x650">
      <div class="projectTitle">
        Hello<span>Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x450">
      <div class="projectTitle">
        Hello<span>Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/520x250">
      <div class="projectTitle">
        Hello<span>Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/475x625">
      <div class="projectTitle">
        Hello<span>Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x655">
      <div class="projectTitle">
        Hello<span>Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x655">
      <div class="projectTitle">
        Hello<span>Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/475x625">
      <div class="projectTitle">
        Hello<span>Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x655">
      <p>Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x655">
      <p>Title</p>
    </div>
</main>
```

**CODEPEN:**
https://codepen.io/Dennisade/pen/gzVZjL?editors=1100

Would be super nice to get some advice here :)

Comment: and what is the pattern here?

Comment: I have to repeat the grid one bye one with the nth-child selector. But I want to avoid this. I want it more like this:
*1st row:* 3 thumbnails
*2nd row:* 1 thumbnails
*3rd row*: 2 thumbnails
Repeat this ^

Comment: But without writing hundreds of selectors

Comment: Why don't you try Sass

Comment: @Duck_dragon thanks for this... do you have some advise/ starting point for this?

Comment: you can refer this link https://css-tricks.com/loops-css-preprocessors/ . Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks... I will give this a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must want to add a `an+b` formula in your `:nth-child()` selector according to the pattern you want.

Here is a working snippet to show you the principle:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
}

.item {
  margin: 50px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
}

.projectTitle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  top: 100%;
}

/* TAKIT: Here is what I'll do: */
.item:nth-child(6n+1) { width: 25%; }
.item:nth-child(6n+2) { width: 25%; }
.item:nth-child(6n+3) { width: 25%; }
.item:nth-child(6n+4) { width: 80%; }
.item:nth-child(6n+5) { width: 40%; }
.item:nth-child(6n)   { width: 40%; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/875x1200">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<br><span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x655">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<br><span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/475x650">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x450">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/875x625">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/655x480">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/475x650">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x450">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/520x250">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/475x625">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x655">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x655">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/475x655">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      Hello<span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x655">
    <p>Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x655">
    <p>Title</p>
  </div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah Nice! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Dennis Glad it helped. :)